# Задержка между кликами JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть простой слайдер, при нажатии на кнопку next включается следующая картинка. Можно ли как-то сделать задержку между кликами чтоб новая картинка успевала занимать свое место? Типа сделал клик, а на следующий клик программа откликнется только через секунду.

Comment: Если вопрос в том можно ли - ответ можно. Если подробностей хотите - так и спрашивайте: "как сделать". (сразу отвечая на второй вопрос, например при клике установить таймер, и переменную(Например CanSlide = false), в таймер прописать "CanSlide = true" При попытке пролистать проверять что переменная "CanSlide == true")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Можно как-то так...**

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button"),
    d_num = document.getElementById("num"),
    num = +document.getElementById("num").textContent;

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  num++;
  d_num.textContent = num;
  button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  setTimeout(() => {
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }, 1000)
});
```

```html
<div id="num">0</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Извиняюсь что не вовремя, но столкнулся со следущей проблемой: первые два клика алгоритм работает без проблем, дальше же, он либо ставит disabled на >1000мс либо вообще не ставит, можете как-то помочь с данной проблемой?

Comment: @Nikita, без кода ничего не понятно, задайте доп. вопрос, а там посмотрим